# How to create directory using HTTPURLConnection with put method. It always creates a file not a directory

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

```
String destURL="https://my-server.com/application/newFolder"

java.net.URL destination = new java.net.URL(destURL);
java.net.HttpURLConnection connection =  (java.net.HttpURLConnection) destination.openConnection();

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/directory");
connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection.connect();
return new HttpStatus(connection.getResponseCode(), connection.getResponseMessage());
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally PUT is used to create content at given location and not a folder.

You need to check what commands your server supports for creating folder (i.e. in the past WebDAV servers would use MKCOL - [Creating Folders (WebDAV)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms878641%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) ). Just changing client side code alone will not enable such functionality.

Comment: makes sense. only way is MKCOL which needs an updated apache version for the applciation

Answer (score 0):

You can't with `HttpURLConnection`. You need to issue a WebDAV MKCOL command, and `HttpURLConnection` won't do it. You can do it with the Apache HTTP client, *if* your web server supports WevDAV.

Comment: makes sense. only way is MKCOL which needs an updated apache version for the applciation